# How to use the Result Set from a Query in the Constraint Editor to conditionally execute SQL Task?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, expressionbuilder

My SQL Script is storing in `@gempar` = `NULL` and in `@beneficiary` = `'2018-01-01'`.
In need to Execute the next Execute SQL Tasks based on the content of those variables. IF `ISNULL(@gempar) = True` then we don't run the following task (because then `@gempar` **is equal to NULL**). On the other hand, IF `ISNULL(@beneficiary) = False` then we run the following task (because `@beneficiary` **is not NULL**).

[image]

The next image is the **Result Set** from the Execute SQL Task:

[image]

I created the 2 variables beneficiary and gempar in SSIS but I am not sure if they should be written as following in the expression column: `@[User::gempar]` and `@[User::beneficiary]` or as they are now on the next image:

[image]

This is the SSIS Control Flow:

[image]

The **Precedence Constraint Editor**'s Output should be True. Why is it not catching the value in `@beneficiary` ?

[image]

I expect the *TRUNCATE GEMPAR TABLES* task to stop and the *TRUNCATE BENE TABLES* task to continue.

Comment: What is your question?   I have no idea what you're trying to ask.  What if `gempar` is true AND `beneficiary` is false?

Comment: I would like to Conditionally Execute TRUNCATE GEMPAR TABLES or/and TRUNCATE BENE TABLES based on the value in the 2 variables (@gempar and @beneficiary). The need is to execute the flow only if the variable is not NULL.

Comment: "I am not sure if they should be written as following in the expression column: @[User::gempar] and @[User::beneficiary] or as they are now on the next image: "   Why don't you try it both ways and see which one works?

Comment: I did it but the two ways are giving me the same result. Which is both pipe lines are running. I need only the right one to execute because @beneficiary is not null.

Comment: Your expression syntax is wrong. It should just be: `LEN(@[User::beneficiary]) > 1`.

Comment: When Evaluating : `LEN(@[User::beneficiary]) > 1`, I have False. It should be True.
Is it mapping well `@[User::beneficiary]` from ssis and `@beneficiary` from ssms?

Comment: When I use Execute SQL tasks to assign a value to a variable, I always alias the column name(s) and then use the column name(s) as the Result Name to assign Result Sets to variables. What is the datatype of `dbo.PARAMS.[Start date]`?

Comment: `[Start Date] datetime`
When creating the variables, what should I write in the Value or Expression column?

Comment: I Solved this issue by using `@[User::beneficiary] != ""` because ssis reads NULL values as empty cells.

Answer (score 2):

SSIS doesn't allow for SSIS variables to be null.  It's somewhat older and in a slightly different context, but this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2007/06/15/optional-date-parameter/) further details SSIS variables in regards to null.  Since the variables you're using are of the string data type, an option compare the variable to a blank string.  Keep in mind, that this **does not** guarantee these variables were null as a result of what was performed in the Execute SQL Task.  You may need to substitute blank strings or another value in your `SELECT` statement for this.  For example, `COALESCE(@beneficiary , '')`.

Right-click the Precedence Constraint between the tasks select Edit.  Then change the Evaluation Operation to **Expression** and add an expression as follows.  Depending on your expected outcome, the Evaluation Operation may need to be changed to **Expression and Constraint**, with the status of the prior task set in the Value field.  The example below returns true when the `@[User::beneficiary]` variable is null, which will allow the following task to execute as you described.  You can reverse this, i.e. use `!=`, for the `@[User::gempar]` variable.

```
@[User::beneficiary]) == ""
```