# how to update tabular data from source tables

Tags: ssas-tabular

I have a simple test setup:

- A SQL Server (2017) with one database, with one table
- A SQL Server Analysis Server (2017, with compatibility level 1400)
- I have created a simple tabular model in Visual Studio with one datasource (the database with one table) and one table

This is my power query:

```
let
  Source = #"SQL/MYCOMPUTER\SQLDEV;SampleDatabase",
  dbo_testTable = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="testTable"]}[Data]
in
  dbo_testTable
```

I have deployed this tabular model to my SSAS instance...

Now my question: if the table in my SQL Server is updated (added records), how can I see these updates reflected in the Tabular Model? Do I have to rerun the Tabular Model somehow?

I have tried "Process Table" in SSMS on the Tabular model table, but it does not get the new records...

Answer (score 1):

Processing a table processes whichever dimension or fact table you selected and this will only read data from the database objects used by this table.  What processing is actually performed will depend on the type of processing that you used.  As far as the question in the answer you posted, Process Full on an entire Tabular model will remove all data from the deployed model, then reload everything and process the hierarchies and measures as well, so yes the new data from the underlying tables will now be in the model for all tables within it after you processed it using this option.  There are multiple processing types that can either be done at the database, table, or partition level.  You can view additional details on these via the Microsoft [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/process-database-table-or-partition-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Why deleted your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444406/how-to-use-the-result-set-from-a-query-in-the-constraint-editor-to-conditionally) it was the correct answer. have you checked the OP comments?

Comment: @Hadi thanks for catching that.  I must have inadvertently deleted the answer and not realized it at the time.  I undeleted the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that on the level of the Database in the SSAS instance, there is an option "Process Database" that has an option "Process Full", which does update all the underlying tables.
But maybe there is a better way to do this?